# date( ) returns 1970-01-01

Tags: php, sql, date, picker

I am using a jquery datepicker with the following format mm/dd/yyyy but I need it to be yyyy-mm-dd for the sql db so I am using this.

```
   $date  = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($startdate));
```

with the following

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO complete_table ( name, startdate) VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$date')";
```

Unfortunately I register 1970-01-01 in the db regardless of what the input is.
Any idea on what I am doing wrong? Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Try echo-ing the output of the strtotime function, if that returns 0, that's your error. The date is the start of UNIX timestamps.

Comment: Please also note that the query, as is, is vulnerable to SQL Injections. If you want to know more about that, please head to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get `1970-01-01` back from `date()` it means that the timestamp is incorrect. That date is the [UNIX epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

When it comes to Javascript (in this case a datepicker) you should always make sure that what you get is, in fact, what you expect it to be. Simply passing it through `strtotime()` will cause problems like the one you have here.

One good way to handle dates is using the [`datetime`](http://php.net/datetime) extension. It has a static method, [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), that will let you parse any date using any format:

```php
// The value from the datepicker
$dpValue = '12/30/2013';

// Parse a date using a user-defined format
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dpValue);

// If the above returns false then the date
// is not formatted correctly
if ($date === false) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    die('Invalid date from datepicker!')
}

// Using the parsed date we can create a
// new one with a formatting of out choosing
$forSQL = $date->format('Y-m-d');

// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

put dateformat in jquery when initializing the datepicker like

```
$( "#id/.class" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
```

This format will insert on mysql db(done on client side), otherwise format it on the server side code.

Answer (score -1):

`$startdate` is invalid and therefor the `strtotime` function returns anything below 86400 (most likely 0), which is the amount of seconds in one day. Please refer to the PHP documentation for the right formatting of `$startdate` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

Answer (score -3):

It is called the epoch. So `startdate` is zero.

Comment: `$startdate` doesn't actually have to be zero, but the result of the `strtotime` function does. Or anything below 86400, to be exact.

Comment: @jeroenvisser101 - One assumes that the problem is that startdate has a value that equates to zero.